# Prove $N\cdot lg(N) = \sum_{k=1}^N(\lfloor lg(k) \rfloor + 2)$ - "Analysis of Algorithms" by R. Sedgewick

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, recursive-algorithms

[image]

This is a problem from "Analysis of Algorithms" by R. Sedgewick. In the context of the merge sort:

> $C_N = N\cdot lg(N)$

*Exercise 1.4*

> Develop a recurrence describing the quantity $C_{N+1} − C_N$ and use this
>    to prove that: $C_N = \sum_{k=1}^N(\lfloor lg(k) \rfloor + 2)$

I don't understand what is meant by "Develop a recurrence ..." in this context. My thoughts:

$$C_{N+1} - C_N = (N+1) \cdot lg(N+1) - N \cdot lg(N) = N \cdot (lg(N+1) - lg(N)) + lg(N + 1) = lg( (1 + \frac{1}{N})^N) + lg(N + 1)$$

As $N$ goes to infinity take the limit:
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{N})^N = e$$

Then:
$$C_{N+1} - C_N = lg(N + 1) + lg(e)$$

Let's represent $C_N$ as a sum, taking into account that $C_0 = 0$:
$$C_N = \sum_{k=1}^N (C_k - C_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^N (lg(k) + lg(e))$$

It is clear that the floor underestimates $lg(n)$ and there are some "leftovers". So may be those leftovers plus $lg(e)$ on average would be equal to 2. How would rigorous proof look like?

Not rigorous proof: note that $0 < leftovers < 1$, log is monotone increasing so on average it would be equal to 0.5. Then 0.5 + $lg(e) = 0.5 + 1.44$ almost 2.

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely at first glance.

This means that

$\begin{array}\\
\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor +2
&=(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln(n)\\
&=(n+1)(\ln(n)+\ln(1+1/n))-n\ln(n)\\
&=n(\ln(n)+\ln(n)+(n+1)\ln(1+1/n))-n\ln(n)\\
&=(n+1)\ln(1+1/n))+\ln(n)\\
&=(n+1)(\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3}))+\ln(n)\\
&=(1-\frac1{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))+(\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3}))+\ln(n)\\
&=\ln(n)+(1+\frac1{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))\\
\text{or}\\
\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor 
&=\ln(n)-1+\frac1{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2})\\
\end{array}
$

However,
if $n = e^m+c$
where $m$ is large
and $0 < c < 1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n)
&=\ln(e^m+c)\\
&=\ln(e^m)+\ln(1+ce^{-m})\\
&=m+ce^{-m}-tc^2/(2e^{2m})\\
\end{array}
$

where
$0 < t \le 1$.

Therefore
$\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor
= m
$
and
$\ln(n)-1
=m+ce^{-m}-tc^2/(2e^{2m})-1
\lt m
$
for
$ce^{-m} < 1$.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, may be I misunderstood something

Comment: Aha! It says when N is a power of 2. Also, I don't know the definition of $C_N$.